# MS Internet Explorer Request Aborted

Tags: codeigniter, internet-explorer, browser-cache, dreamhost

I have a codeigniter webapp being accessed through https.

Everything works as expected in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera. When using Internet Explorer (V11), about half the time, I get a page saying:

> This page can’t be displayed
>   •Make sure the web address https://... is correct
>     ...

When I look at the Developer Tools (F12), I see that the last request has Result (Aborted)

Localhost:

```
URL/test.php Result / (Aborted)  ......... Initiator / navigate  
URL/test.php Result / 200        ......... Initiator / click
```

sometimes the first request succeeds (200) and the second line doesn't appear

Internet Host:

```
URL/test.php Result / (Aborted)  ......... Initiator / navigate
```

I never get the Initiator/click line when connecting to this host.

If I hit enter in the browser bar (initiator/navigate), I get result (Aborted) every second time.
If I repeat (press enter in the address bar again) it succeeds/fails/succeeds
However if I click reload or press F5 (initiator/refresh) it works every time.
If I leave a couple of minutes between requests (of whatever kind) it also works every time

I thought this had something to do with the cache. I tried to add extra headers

> Pragma:no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
>   Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT

It seems the hosted server setup has some kind of default configuration that excludes my Pragma/Cache-Control/Expires lines, as these do not appear in the response headers when the pages are served from the internet, but do from localhost

IE is reporting a different User-Agent String when connecting to my hosted server on the internet compared to localhost

Localhost:

```
 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E;
   .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; 
   AskTbFXTV5/5.9.1.14019)
```

Internet:

```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Any clues greatly appreciated

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally had the idea of **clearing the browsing history**.

This happened by coincidence as I was working on some .css changes at the time and those changes didn't seem to get reflected when reloading the page.

I cleared *Temporary Internet files*, *Cookies* and *History*. I assume clearing *Temporary Internet files* is what cured the problem.